# Superclass and Subclasses Interchange?

Tags: java, inheritance, superclass

I understand that

```
Superclass object = new subclass();
```

works and makes sense, but does

```
Subclass object = new superclass();
```

work too. I'm guessing it wouldn't since you cannot be sure that the superclass "shares the same properties" as the subclass or am I just completely off? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ask yourself this. All `Dogs` (child) are `Animals` (parent). But are All `Animals` `Dogs`?.

Comment: `I'm guessing it wouldn't since you cannot be sure that the superclass "shares the same properties" as the subclass` This is correct.

Comment: How long would it take for you to try it out? Surely less than it took to create this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Vehicle x=new Car();
```

so Car is a type of Vehicle.

```
Car x=new Vehicle();  // compilation error here
```

Vehicle is a type of Car? Does that make any sense? **NO**